# Magento 1 : Few product urls are getting 403 error

Tags: magento-1.9, product-urls, http-status-403

Most of the product urls are working fine. But Few product urls are getting 403 error.

Answer (score 0):

403 Forbidden error? Try to give `sudo chmod -R 777' in the root project.

Comment: Already tried but its not worked

Comment: Did I face 403 Forbidden error? for few products only. Most of the product working fine

Comment: show me console log in browser

Comment: getting following error on console - 

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)